# Reading connection string from Environment variable using Powershell

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, environment-variables

I have asp.net mvc application, for which database connection string is placed in Environment variable `DbConn` as

```
Min Pool Size=20;Application Name=***;**initial catalog=*****;server=***;Integrated Security=True;
```

Now my question is how to read this connection string using Powershell script. I know how to read the entire connection string `Get-ChildItem Env:DBConn`,but I need a portion of it like the initial catalog,server etc.

Please guide me in resolving this.

Comment: Deleting after getting valid anwer? What was that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse and tokenize the connection string with [`-split`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx), [Trim()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) and a hashtable:

```
$DBConnValues = @{}
$env:DBConn.Trim(";") -split ";" |ForEach-Object { 
    $key,$value = $_ -split "="
    $DBConnValues[$key] = $value
}
```

Now you can access each property by name:

```
PS C:\> $DBConnValues["Server"]
ServerName
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a perfect case for `ConvertFrom-StringData` so that you can make it into a custom object.

```
$props = $env:DBConn -replace ";","`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData
$dbConn = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props
```

`ConvertFrom-StringData` wants a string where each line is a key value pair. We get just that by replacing the semicolons with newlines. It returns a hashtable which we feed to `New-object` to get a custom PowerShell object. Then you can use the new object like you would any in PowerShell.

```
$dbConn."Min Pool Size"
```